# How to split excel records into multiple records using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have data in the following format:

| Start date | End date | Start time | End time | Volume | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/12/22 | 9/12/22 | 10:00 | 12:00 | 50 | 300 |

Is there a way using formulas to split that record into hourly data? I was hoping for something that could work automatically without using vba if possible.

This is the output I am looking for:

| Start Date | End Date | Time | Volume | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/12/22 | 9/12/22 | 10 | 50 | 300 |
| 9/12/22 | 9/12/22 | 11 | 50 | 300 |

This could be done by creating an empty date time series and using sum-ifs. I would like to avoid that if possible as each day only has a few hours of prices/volumes

Comment: Wouldn't the volume and price be divided by the number of lines you create from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ms365, try:

[image]

Formula in `A5`:

```
=LET(r,A2:F3,REDUCE(HSTACK(A1:B1,"Time",E1:F1),SEQUENCE(ROWS(r)),LAMBDA(a,b,LET(x,INDEX(r,b,1)+INDEX(r,b,3),y,INDEX(r,b,2)+INDEX(r,b,4),VSTACK(a,DROP(REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(--TEXT(y-x,"[hh]")),LAMBDA(c,d,VSTACK(c,HSTACK(INT(x+TIME(d-{1,0},,)),INDEX(r,b,3)+TIME(d-1,,),INDEX(r,b,{5,6}))))),1))))))
```

Above is flexible enough to have Start- and End Date to be different.